# Django CMS (3.6.0) automatic language switch/detection not working as intended

Tags: django, internationalization, django-cms

**Expected behaviour** would be that a newly visiting person with FR as first setting in HTTP header should see the french version of the page (which is existing and set as language in settings, but not as default. manual language switch is working).

Accoriding to django docs language should be determined in the following order

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference

1. language prefix in the requested URL
2. cookie
3. Accept-Language HTTP header
4. Default Settings

**Actual behaviour** correctly switches navigation nodes (django cms menu) to french, but not cms plugin content (displayed in default language).

```
#MIDDLEWARE SETTINGS (order as mentioned in docs)

'cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
'webpack.middleware.WebpackDevserverMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.contrib.admindocs.middleware.XViewMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

##################################################################
# multisite language handling
##################################################################
AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES = {
    'de': _('Deutsch'),
    'fr': _('Französisch'),
    'it': _('Italiano'),
    'en': _('English'),
}
SITE_LANGUAGES = config('SITE_LANGUAGES', default='de,fr', cast=Csv())
LANGUAGE_CODE = SITE_LANGUAGES[0]
LANGUAGES = [(k, v) for k, v in AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES.items() if k in SITE_LANGUAGES]
```

Is CMS_LANGUAGES needed if SITE_LANGUAGES are set. In Django CMS all relevant options in page tree are available. I could not see any different behaviour if set.

Any ideas what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: Have you created the plugin content for all languages? Generally there are language specific versions of CMS content. Switch to the French version of the page, and make sure all content is correctly in French, then publish the page.

Comment: Yes, content is existing for all languages. I just realized that it's an existing problem. https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/6448

It can be fixed by adding prefix_default_language=True to urls.py and if prefix for default language is not wished, there is a patch existing.

Comment: I will leave the question open for now, because the mentioned fix might be not  be the proper way to fix the issue.